# Ubuntu isnt in the boot list anymore?

Tags: 13.04

I have ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop beside windows 7. it was working fine. when, outra nowhere, i restarted the laptop, but no ubuntu in the boot list. directly goes to windows and boot up.

any suggestion is more than welcome ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend you Check This out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
And Make a boot rescue disk.

If you just want the Easy Steps On How to fix your grub, Check This Out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows